# Showing that a system of Diophantine equations will have irrational solutions as well as integers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Solve $\begin{cases} 3xy-2y^2=-2\\ 9x^2+4y^2=10 \end{cases}$

Rearranging the 2nd equation to $x^2=\dfrac{10-4y^2}{9} \Longrightarrow 0\leq x^2 \leq 1$ if $x^2=1$ than $y=\pm\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $x=\pm1$ but how do I show there exists two more solutions to this equation by using number theory vs college algebra. Does it have to do with the relationship that $0\leq y^2 \leq 10$ ? So does this say anything about solutions being irrational?

Answer (score 1):

If you add five times the first equation plus the second, you get $9 x^2 + 15 x y - 6 y^2 = 0,$ or
$$ 3 (3x - y)(x+ 2 y) = 0. $$
So the choices lie along either the line $$ y = 3x $$ or the line $$ y = \frac{-x}{2}.  $$

From the ellipse equation $9 x^2 + 4 y^2 = 10,$ we get either $45 x^2 = 10$ and $9 x^2 = 2$ and $(3x)^2 = 2,$ or $10 x^2 = 10$ and $x^2 = 1.$

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense so much more sense. This shows I'll easily have 4 solutions and thats where $\dfrac{\pm \sqrt{2}}{3}$ comes in.

Answer (score 0):

The number of solutions has nothing to do with some of the intersection points being rational, which is a happy coincidence. The way to approach this problem is plain old algebra. Add twice the first equation to the second, and divide through by 3 to get

$$2x y + 3x^2 = 2.$$

Then manipulating the second equation gives

$$9x^4 + 4x^2y^2 = 10x^2$$
$$9x^4 + (2-3x^2)^2 = 10x^2$$

This is a quadratic equation in $x^2$, which has solutions $x^2 = 1, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}.$

When $x^2 = 1$, from the second equation we have $y^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, checking these in the first equation reveals that two of the sign choices are spurious, leaving $(-1, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(1, -\frac{1}{2})$ as true solutions.

Similarly, when $x^2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$, you get two solutions $(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}, -\sqrt{2})$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}, \sqrt{2})$.

Since your two polynomials have no common polynomial divisor, by Bezout's Theorem, the system 
of polynomial equations has at most four solutions, and we have found them all. (Geometrically, your equations describe a nondegenerate hyperbola and ellipse, which can intersect in at most four points.)

Comment: I like the bit with Bezout's Theorem.

Comment: So since the degree of the polynomial is 4 than there will be 4 solutions. That makes sense but what did I do wrong in the method I went about in solving this. I used a bit of logic and some Diophantine equation experience to solve this. How do I know if these equations will have 4 solutions by looking at them and using number theory.

Comment: For finding solutions with integral $x$, your approach is a good one. But Number Theory seems an odd tool for the job of determining the number of real vs complex solutions to polynomial equations, not least because the general theory of quadratic Diophantine equations is not elementary.